# Getting an error message n is not a function

Tags: node.js, netlify, netlify-function

I am writing a serverless netlify function when I hit /:uid endpoint, it shows me this error message `n is not a function` but when I hit / endpoint, it doesn't throw an error.
Please help me with this.

src/api.js file code

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());

const fetchWithToken = (endpoint, method = "GET") => {
  return fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}${endpoint}`, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `token ${process.env.TOKEN}`,
    },
  });
};

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("JDKJKFJ");
});

router.get("/:uid", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchWithToken(`/${req.params.uid}`, "GET");
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
});

app.use("/.netlify/functions/api", router);

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

error message

```
TypeError: n is not a function
    at /Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:159:3133
    at /Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:159:3232
    at o.handle_request (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:120:783)
    at o (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:113:879)
    at d.dispatch (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:113:901)
    at o.handle_request (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:120:783)
    at /Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:2533
    at f (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:3502)
    at f (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:3696)
    at Function.v.process_params (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:3839)
    at g (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:2476)
    at Function.v.handle (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:3340)
    at p (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:238)
    at o.handle_request (/Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:120:783)
    at /Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:2905
    at /Users/rishipurwar/codingspace-proxy-server/functions/api.js:106:2927
Response with status 500 in 57 ms.
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Hello there,
Here is the repo link: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/codingspace-proxy-server

Comment: and I don't know what is stack trace

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: Just added an error message, please check

Comment: and I am also not able to access the env variables in api.js file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.json()` to the returned value from fetch:

```
try {
    let data = await fetchWithToken(`/${req.params.uid}`, "GET");
    data = await data.json()
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
```

Comment: still getting same error message

Comment: I don't know why I am also not able to access env inside the api.js file

Comment: @RishiPurwar I just checked your repo, and I saw that you're using netlify-lambda to run your program.
I think the solution would be to change the way you are using the env variables, you can check a detailed guide on this [Github issue answer](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/118#issuecomment-506973346)

Comment: Is it possible for you to write a proper answer? so that It'll be helpful for someone in the future

Comment: If I directly use the values instead of using env variables. still, it's showing me an error.